# Magento 2: Skipping Shopping Cart Page after Add to Cart

Tags: magento2, php, event-observer, addtocart, shopping-cart

I'm using Magento 2 CE Version 2.1.0.

I have Googled & also referred some StackOverflow Q&A.

I have done the following things:

**app\code\Custom\Module\etc\frontend\events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_predispatch_skip_shoppingcart">
        <observer name="skip_shopping_cat_page" instance="Custom\Module\Observer\SkipShoppingCartObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**app\code\Custom\Module\Observer\SkipShoppingCartObserver.php**

```
namespace Custom\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class SkipShoppingCartObserver implements ObserverInterface {


    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag
     */
    protected $_actionFlag;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface
     */
    protected $messageManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface
     */
    protected $redirect;

    /**
     * @var DataPersistorInterface
     */
    private $dataPersistor;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Captcha\Helper\Data $helper
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag $actionFlag
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect
     */
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Captcha\Helper\Data $helper, \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag $actionFlag, \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager, \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect
    ) {
        $this->_helper = $helper;
        $this->_actionFlag = $actionFlag;
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->redirect = $redirect;
    }

    public function afterAddToCart(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
        $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
        $response = $observer->getResponse();
        echo 2;
        exit;
        $response->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl("checkout/onepage"));
        Mage::getSingleton("checkout/session")->setNoCartRedirect(true);
    }

    /**
     *     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
        $actionName = $observer->getEvent()->getRequest()->getFullActionName();
        $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
        $controller->getResponse();
        echo 1;
        exit;
    }
}
```

After a product has been added to cart, it's not going neither of above function.

**[UPDATE]**

Thanks @Raphael for great help. It's working fine on Product Detail Page, but in listing still have issue. In listing after clicking on "Add to Cart" it's calling below services & Stays on same page. May be AJAX issue? Not sure

It keep displaying "Adding.." in Grey

[image]

Comment: Hi SO Community, Please guide me to achieve functionality. Thanks

Comment: Guys less than 1 day left please try to help if u can. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well it's because **the event you're trying to observe never gets dispatched by Magento.** In Magento 2 `controller_action_predispatch_skip_shoppingcart` does not exist. I assume you wrote that event name by yourself assuming it had to be custom.

You need to **replace that with `controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_cart_add` to observe the process after a product has been added to cart.**

On top of that, you never call your `afterAddToCart` method in your observer, so only your `execute()` method will be called.

Finally, you have some Magento 1 code in there, so you need to replace:

```
    $response->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl("checkout/onepage"));
    Mage::getSingleton("checkout/session")->setNoCartRedirect(true);
```

With:

```
    $response->setRedirect($this->_urlManager->getUrl('checkout/onepage'));
    $this->_checkoutSession->setNoCartRedirect(true);
```

Where `$this->_urlManager` needs to be injected via Dependency Injection using the `\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface` class and `$this->_checkoutSession` using the `\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session` class.

Comment: Hi @Raphael. Yes u r correct it's Custom. Thanks for answer i have changed things now i think issue with `$actionName = $observer->getEvent()->getRequest()->getFullActionName();
        $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
        $response->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl("checkout/onepage"));
        Mage::getSingleton("checkout/session")->setNoCartRedirect(true);` I think last 2 lines are for Magento 1 need to convert in Magento 2

Comment: @AnkitShah see my updated answer ;)

Comment: Thanks @Raphael. I updated code as you said final code will be `public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
        $actionName = $observer->getEvent()->getRequest()->getFullActionName();
        $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
        $controller->getResponse()->setRedirect($this->_urlManager->getUrl('checkout'));
        return $this->_checkoutSession->setNoCartRedirect(true);
    }` . Still issue persist. When i Add to Cart product from Product Listing. It will stay on Same Page. Not redicting to Checkout Page.

Comment: I have checked with FireBug /Inspect Element it's going to Observer & Checkout page. But it stays the same Category page. Not redirecting. Strange. It's working fine from Product Detail page :). Issue with Only Listing

Comment: @AnkitShah not sure why it doesn't work on listing page.

Comment: Thanks @Raphael for helping this out. Let me see why it's not working on Listing Page. I'm attaching screenshot of service called in Listing in question.

Comment: Hi @Raphael can you please help me out to solve it's 50% Done. 50% Pending.

Comment: HI @Raphael any updates??

Answer (score 0):

It will not work in listing page so you have to create one plugin for **Checkout/Controller/Cart/Add.php** and write redirect logic here.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps for redirection to checkout page (Skip shopping cart page):

> 1. Create default.xml file at view/frontend/layout directory in your module to override list.phtml and addtocart.phtml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
                <action method="setTemplate">
                    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
                </action>
            </referenceBlock>
            <referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
                <action method="setTemplate">
                    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::product/list.phtml</argument>
                </action>
            </referenceBlock>
         </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> 2. Override both files in your module and get base url in those template files
> 3. Add below line in both files inside form tag

```
<input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="<?= $baseUrl."checkout"; ?>" >
where $baseUrl -> Is base URL of your site.
```

**NOTE: In addtocart.phtml file you can't find form tag so, you can add above line before**

```
<div class="box-tocart">
```