# Magento 2: Change the action of add to cart button on product and category pages to checkout page?

Tags: magento-2.1, addtocart, buy-now

I am new to Magento 2 and want to change the action of add to cart button on product and category pages directly to the checkout page.

[Magento 2: Skipping Shopping Cart Page after Add to Cart](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/138035/magento-2-skipping-shopping-cart-page-after-add-to-cart)

I referred to the solution given in above link, but not able to find the directory which is required to be updated -- event.xml

Answer (score 1):

Assume that add to Cart url is `www.example.com/checkout/cart/add`.

In this case, you can use event ***`checkout_cart_add_product_complete`*** .

Using this event,You can ***Redirect to last page from here you have click on AddtoCart***

**Observer**

```
<?php
# app/code/Devamitbera/CartRedirect/Observer/ObserverToskipCartgotoCheckout
namespace Devamitbera\CartRedirect\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class ObserverToskipCartgotoCheckout implements ObserverInterface
{


    /**
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
     */
    protected $_urlManager;


    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface
     */
    protected $messageManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface
     */
    protected $redirect;


    private $_pageConfig;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag $actionFlag
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag $actionFlag,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlManager,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config $pageConfig     
    ) {
        $this->_actionFlag = $actionFlag;
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->_urlManager = $urlManager;
        $this->redirect = $redirect;

    }

    /**
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $request = $observer->getRequest();
        $response = $observer->getResponse();
        $product  = $observer->getProduct();
      if (!$request->isAjax()) {
            $url = $this->_urlManager->getUrl('checkout/index/index');
            //$this->_objectManager->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->critical($url);
            $request->setParam('return_url',$url);
        }
    }

}
```

**event file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
#app/code/Devamitbera/CartRedirect/etc/events.xml
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
        <event name="checkout_cart_add_product_complete">
        <observer name="forrceToCheckout" instance="Devamitbera\CartRedirect\Observer\ObserverToskipCartgotoCheckout" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Comment: Does it mean that a new file has to be added in custom theme module directory with the event defined in the discussion.

Comment: I have uploaded a customized theme over Magento/blank, and I am not sure where to add these custom file for execution in the custom theme only.  The directory structure is same as Luma. Can you direct me to the correct path for execution

Comment: I have added the directories as required in App/code. I took a reference of this article - https://www.cloudways.com/blog/add-additional-options-in-magento-2/. Still I get Error 503. What might be the error in execution, I'm not able to reach there.

Comment: @avatar,you need to create a custom module for this

Comment: getting this url  503 internal server